# Why the first if statement conditional is ignored and the last else is executed?

Tags: python

When I type in John and 0 the "John is great" statement is not executed. I don't understand why.
I know that the question might be really simple but I checked the code in Java and it was working correctly.

```
print("Hello world")
myName = input("What is your name?\n")
myVar = input("Enter a number: ") 

if(myName == "John" and myVar == 0):
    print("John is great")
elif(myName == "Bob"):
    print("You are ok")
else:
    print("Hello world")
```

Comment: Both variables are `str` values; you are comparing one of them to an *`int`*, so that is always false.

Comment: so all inputs in python are strings?

Comment: Yes. All inputs are strings. If you want to read an input as integer, you have to do a cast: `myvar = int(input("Enter a number: "))`.

Comment: @JuliaK Thank you, it worked ;)

Answer (score 3):

`myVar` is `str` type. **Not** `int` type.
You should fix `myVar = int(input("Enter a number: "))`

Answer (score 0):

`0` and `"0"` are two different values. `0 == 0` is true; `0 == "0"` is false.

`input` *always* returns a `str`, so entering `0` sets `myVar` to `"0"`, not `0`.

```
if myName == "John" and myVar == "0":
```